# PHP Undefined variable/call do a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, function, class, undefined

System is giving me an error on the last if. Undefined variable on $nomeportefolio. Call do a member function ()addideasportefolio on a non-object.
If i move these 2 lines to the if before this one changing the function variables, it works, but i need it on the last if! Can someone help?

```
    <?php

include ("Ideia.php");

$handle = @fopen("C:\Users\Bia\Desktop\Projecto ES/input.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    $booleanuser = FALSE;
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        $partial = substr($buffer, 0, 4);
        $nomeuser;
        $iduser;
        $saldo = substr($buffer, 0, 5);
        $portefolio = substr($buffer, 0, 9);
        $nomeportefolio;


        if ($partial == "user") {
            $booleanuser = TRUE;
            $nomeuser=substr($buffer, 0, 5);
            $iduser=substr($buffer, 4, 1);
            $nomeuser = new User($iduser);
        }

        if ($booleanuser == FALSE) {
            if ($partial == "idea") {
                $nomeideia=substr($buffer, 0, 5);
                $idideia=substr($buffer, 4, 1);
                $nomeideia = new Ideia($idideia);
            }
        }

        if ($saldo == "Saldo"){
            $nomeuser->addsaldo(substr($buffer, 7));
            echo $nomeuser->greetuser();    
        }

        if ($portefolio == "Portfolio"){
            $nomeportefolio="portefolio".$iduser;
            $nomeportefolio = new Portefolio($iduser,$iduser);

        }
        if ($partial == "idea"){
            $nomeportefolio->addideiasportefolio($iduser,$iduser);
            //função que mostra os ids das ideias no portefólio
            echo $nomeportefolio->mostraportefolio();
        }


    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `$nomeportefolio="portefolio".$iduser;`, since you overwrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Call to a member function on a non-object` means that you are trying to use a function on a variable that is not an object.

In this case, `$nomeportefolio->addideiasportefolio($iduser,$iduser);`

But *why* is that happening ? Simple, you are setting `$nomeportefolio` to be an instance of the `Portefolio` class only on the following part of the code:

```
if ($portefolio == "Portfolio"){
        $nomeportefolio="portefolio".$iduser;
        $nomeportefolio = new Portefolio($iduser,$iduser);

    }
```

But what if `$portefolio` is *not* equals to "Portfolio" but `$partial` *is* equals to *"idea"* ?

Simple :P It tries to call the function `->addideiasportefolio()` on the `$nomeportefolio` that is a *non-object* as the `if($portefolio == "portfolio")` didn't executed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `$nomeportefolio` within an if statement inside a while. Sine the `if ($partial == "idea")` conditional **calls* `$nomeportefolio` but does not set it, you run the risk of being somewhere in the loop where `$portefolio !== "Portfolio"` yet so it was not set. What you need to do is put the "idea" check inside the portfolio if statement:

```
    if ($portefolio == "Portfolio"){
        $nomeportefolio="portefolio".$iduser;
        $nomeportefolio = new Portefolio($iduser,$iduser);

        if ($partial == "idea"){
            $nomeportefolio->addideiasportefolio($iduser,$iduser);
            //função que mostra os ids das ideias no portefólio
            echo $nomeportefolio->mostraportefolio();
        }
    }
```